# Derivative with summation operator in the exponent of $e$

Tags: derivatives, vector-spaces, summation

What is the derivative when the summation operator is in the exponent of $e$, such as:

$$\frac{d}{d\mathbf{x}}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-\mathbf{\hat{x}}}}\right)=\frac{d}{d\mathbf{x}}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-\sum_{i} a_ix_i+b_i}}\right),$$

where $\mathbf{a}=[a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n]$ and $\mathbf{b}=[b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n]$ are constant vectors.

**I tried the following using chain rule:**

$\frac{d}{d\mathbf{x}}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-\mathbf{\hat{x}}}}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-\mathbf{\hat{x}}}}\right)\times\left(1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-\mathbf{\hat{x}}}}\right)\times\mathbf{a}^T$

Comment: May I ask where this task comes from? Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Invisible the goal is to approximate $f(x)=\sigma\left(\sum_{i}\left(a_i*x_i+b_i\right)\right)$ using first order taylor series. $\sigma$ is the sigmid function.

Comment: You're on the right track, except the $a_i$ should be in a vector, not a summation

Comment: Thank you! the approximation is similar to what $f(x)$ gives for every root point and very close around it.